# Python string substitution picking up junk characters in api requests

Tags: python-3.x, string, api, python-requests, pagerduty

I am using Pagerduty python api client - pdpyras And below is the block of code

```
session = APISession(api_token)
changedate = os.popen("date -u -d '24 hours ago' +'%FT%T%.2Z'").read()
print(changedate)
changeurl = "change_events?include[]=integration&since=" + changedate
print(changeurl)
change_dump = session.rget(changeurl)
print(change_dump[0])
```

This should ideally get me the 1st event from change-events page of pagerduty. However, it fails due to the junk characters that gets added in the changeurl when it is passed to session.rget

See the below output

```
2021-03-26T09:47:53.2Z

change_events?include[]=integration&since=2021-03-26T09:47:53.2Z

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dailyincidents.py", line 28, in <module>
    change_dump = session.rget(changeurl)
  File "/Users/saha/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdpyras.py", line 190, in call
    return method(self, url, **kw)
  File "/Users/saha/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdpyras.py", line 143, in call
    r = raise_on_error(method(self, path, **pass_kw))
  File "/Users/saha/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdpyras.py", line 84, in raise_on_error
    ), response=r
pdpyras.PDClientError: GET /change_events?include%5B%5D=integration&since=2021-03-26T09:47:53.2Z%0A: API responded with non-success status (400)
```

The problem here is the junk characters you see in the last line of error "include%5B%5D" and then "%0A" in the end. Because if I run the below code block directly, I am able to successfully pull the details.

`change_dump = session.rget("change_events?include[]=integration&since=2021-03-26T09:47:53.2Z")`

The issue occurs only when the string gets substituted, it takes these junk characters. Not sure how it gets picked and how to get around this. Any pointers?

**EDIT**

I was able to partly get rid of the junk characters. However, there is still one at the end, which I am not sure how to. Below is the change I did.

```
parameters = "include[]=integration&since=" + changedate
change_dump = session.rget("change_events", params=parameters)
```

Now, the error is like below

> pdpyras.PDClientError: GET
> /change_events?include[]=integration&since=2021-03-26T14:14:08.2Z%0A:
> API responded with non-success status (400)

As you can see, now the last 3 characters in the url which is %0A: is causing the problem. Any pointers please?

Comment: Looks like the string gets urlencoded. `[` becomes `%5B`, etc.

Comment: And %0A is newline, which `date` adds to any output format (specified or defaulted) and causes the extra blank lines 'after' your `print`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below format should work for you.

```
parameters = "include[]=integration&since=" + changedate
change_dump = session.rget("change_events",params=parameters.rstrip('\n').replace("\n", ""))
```